# Is there an external public archive of Gitorious projects?

Tags: open-source, gitorious

A certain open source project is hosted at Gitorious. Suppose that at some future point X they decide to close source / delete their project from Gitorious.

Will there exist a public archive of the source code, in something like [The Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

No, except someone keeps his clone of the repository and makes it public somewhere else.

If you want to mirror git repositories, see [my blog entry](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/mirror-sourceforge-git-github.htm) about it.